# Grab itemName data attribute from html element

Tags: javascript

I was trying to test a few novice tricks from a project tutorial. Wanted to create a small scale task app and ran into a weird problem. The last document.addEventListener below should theoretically call the closest element with the class name of ".name" should be detected since its in the same parent div with the button. However it is returning NULL. Am I applying the .closest() method wrong?

The event listener detects the button after everytime a task is created. Not sure why it returns NULL when, after creating the task via addTaskButton, the task with the class name of ".name". I even tried to create a data attribute id based off of the taskName itself to see if it'll detect, but still NULL / erroring.

```
const list = []

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const itemContainer = document.querySelector('.item');
const addTaskButton = document.querySelector('.add-task');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task-name');


function renderTasks(){
    itemContainer.innerHTML = ''
    list.forEach(task => {
        const itemElement = document.createElement('div')
     
        itemElement.innerHTML = `
            <div class="name">
                ${task.taskName}
            </div>
            <button class="retrieval">Retrieve ID</button>
        `
        itemElement.dataset.itemName = task.taskName
        itemContainer.appendChild(itemElement);
    })
}

addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    list.push({ taskName: taskInput.value})


    renderTasks()
})



document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if(e.target.matches('.retrieval')){
        const taskName = e.target.closest('.name');
        console.log(taskName)
    }
})
```

Comment: you could call `document.querySelector(".name");` in the console just to see if that works

Comment: That is a good check. it shows NULL but I know the innerHTML is working though.. the task item is populating the HTML source.. for some reason I can't seem to target it correctly after I hit my retrieval button. Interesting...

Comment: You could try creating the div with `document.createElement` then appending it to your other div, and giving it the class dynamically with `div.setAttribute("class", "name")`, It would effectively do the same thing but maybe the problem has something to do with the fact that the element was created from a string in `.innerHTML` of another element

Comment: Ok, I double checked the mdn article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) it says "closestElement is the Element which is the closest *ancestor* of the selected element. It may be null." I think that means it only looks for parents and parents of parents and so on not 'siblings'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I double checked the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) it says:

> closestElement is the Element which is the closest ancestor of the
> selected element. It may be null.

That means it only looks for parents and parents of parents and so on, not 'siblings'.

Comment: I agree. Thank you!! I totally misunderstood the MND article and I was setting the data attribute onto the "fictional" div I created from createElement. Attention to detail on my end was critical